# Насчет пропорций определенного div-a

Tags: javascript, html, css

Если добавить на страницу картинку, я давать ей ширину, к примеру, 60% от страницы, она будет масштабироваться в соответствии со своими пропорциями. То бишь форма ее останется прежней, но размер ее будет изменяться в зависимости от разрешения экрана/размера окна.

Если же так сделать с каким-либо div-ом, добавив при этом еще и высоту, ибо без нее он не будет отображаться, он будет растягиваться как ему угодно при масштабировании окна. Как сделать его..пропорции фиксированными?

Очень бы хотелось НЕ прибегать к Javascript, но если без него не получится, тогда и его можно использовать. Вопрос срочной важности. Был бы благодарен за хотя бы относительное объяснение кода JavaScript, если напишете)

Спасибо огромное всем отвечающим.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12121309/815386

Comment: думаю, следует добавить, что в этом диве будут еще дивы, которые должны будут тоже масштабирвоаться

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Пример -- http://jsfiddle.net/NJrnz/1/

CSS:

```
.aspect-ratio {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: relative;
}

.aspect-ratio_1-2 { padding-top: 50%; }
.aspect-ratio_2-3 { padding-top: 66.666666667%; }
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!

Но одно но!
Что еще добавить, чтобы див масштабировался не только при горизонтальном изменении окна, но и при вертикальном? Я был бы вам еще более безумно благодарен за ответ!

Comment: А вот тут без JS никак.