# Продолжение моего вопроса про пропорции div-a

Tags: html, вёрстка, javascript, css

Один отличный человек ответил на мой вопрос именно так, как я хотел

Тот вопрос: [Насчет пропорций определенного div-a](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/260512/javascript-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-div-a-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE)

Блок действительно изменяется в размерах при **горизонтальном** изменении окна. Как сделать, чтобы он еще и подгонялся под вертикальное изменение, сохраняя пропорции? То бишь, к примеру, слева и справа у него было **от** 10% отступа, и сверху и снизу тоже. И при растягивании окна его пропорции все-равно сохранялись? В общем как он по горизонтальном растягивании изменяется, так же нужно и при вертикальном.

Надеюсь понятно объяснил.. Я аж поник, когда понял, что идея недоделана. Сейчас сижу весь в грусти и печали))

Огромнейшее спасибо за ответ

Comment: Вам уже ответили только JS.

Comment: @soledar10 Подскажите, как?